# Integrating CCS server in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using this tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/#comment-149345 for chat application in android.But i am bit confused with server side integration for android app.Also i don't find any server URL for smack client connection. Please help me with this...

```
public class SmackCcsClient {

    static final String REG_ID_STORE = "gcmchat.txt";   

    static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "SM";
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SmackCcsClient");

    public static final String GCM_SERVER = "gcm.googleapis.com";
    public static final int GCM_PORT = 5235;

    public static final String GCM_ELEMENT_NAME = "gcm";
    public static final String GCM_NAMESPACE = "google:mobile:data";

    static Random random = new Random();
    XMPPConnection connection;
    ConnectionConfiguration config;

    /**
     * XMPP Packet Extension for GCM Cloud Connection Server.
     */
    class GcmPacketExtension extends DefaultPacketExtension {
        String json;

        public GcmPacketExtension(String json) {
            super(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE);
            this.json = json;
        }

        public String getJson() {
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        public String toXML() {
            return String.format("<%s xmlns=\"%s\">%s</%s>", GCM_ELEMENT_NAME,
                    GCM_NAMESPACE, json, GCM_ELEMENT_NAME);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public Packet toPacket() {
            return new Message() {
                // Must override toXML() because it includes a <body>
                @Override
                public String toXML() {

                    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                    buf.append("<message");
                    if (getXmlns() != null) {
                        buf.append(" xmlns=\"").append(getXmlns()).append("\"");
                    }
                    if (getLanguage() != null) {
                        buf.append(" xml:lang=\"").append(getLanguage())
                                .append("\"");
                    }
                    if (getPacketID() != null) {
                        buf.append(" id=\"").append(getPacketID()).append("\"");
                    }
                    if (getTo() != null) {
                        buf.append(" to=\"")
                                .append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getTo()))
                                .append("\"");
                    }
                    if (getFrom() != null) {
                        buf.append(" from=\"")
                                .append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getFrom()))
                                .append("\"");
                    }
                    buf.append(">");
                    buf.append(GcmPacketExtension.this.toXML());
                    buf.append("</message>");
                    return buf.toString();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public SmackCcsClient() {
        // Add GcmPacketExtension
        ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME,
                GCM_NAMESPACE, new PacketExtensionProvider() {

                    @Override
                    public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser)
                            throws Exception {
                        String json = parser.nextText();
                        GcmPacketExtension packet = new GcmPacketExtension(json);
                        return packet;
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random message id to uniquely identify a message.
     *
     * <p>
     * Note: This is generated by a pseudo random number generator for
     * illustration purpose, and is not guaranteed to be unique.
     *
     */
    public String getRandomMessageId() {
        return "m-" + Long.toString(random.nextLong());
    }

    /**
     * Sends a downstream GCM message.
     */
    public void send(String jsonRequest) {
        Packet request = new GcmPacketExtension(jsonRequest).toPacket();
        connection.sendPacket(request);
    }

    /**
     * Handles an upstream data message from a device application.
     *
     * <p>
     * This sample echo server sends an echo message back to the device.
     * Subclasses should override this method to process an upstream message.
     */
    public void handleIncomingDataMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {

        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();

        // PackageName of the application that sent this message.
        String category = jsonObject.get("category").toString();

        // Use the packageName as the collapseKey in the echo packet
        String collapseKey = "echo:CollapseKey";
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> payload = (Map<String, String>) jsonObject
                .get("data");

        String action = payload.get("ACTION");

        if ("ECHO".equals(action)) {

            String clientMessage = payload.get("CLIENT_MESSAGE");
            payload.put(MESSAGE_KEY, "ECHO: " + clientMessage);

            // Send an ECHO response back
            String echo = createJsonMessage(from, getRandomMessageId(),
                    payload, collapseKey, null, false);
            send(echo);
        } else if ("SIGNUP".equals(action)) {
            try {
                String userName = payload.get("USER_NAME");
                writeToFile(userName, from);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if ("USERLIST".equals(action)) {

            Map<String, String> regIdMap = readFromFile();
            String users = "";
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : regIdMap.entrySet()) {
                users = users + entry.getKey() + ":";
            }
            payload.put(MESSAGE_KEY, "USERLIST");       
            payload.put("USERLIST",users);

            String message = createJsonMessage(from, getRandomMessageId(),
                    payload, collapseKey, null, false);
            send(message);
        } else if ("CHAT".equals(action)) {

            Map<String, String> regIdMap = readFromFile();
            payload.put(MESSAGE_KEY, "CHAT");           
            String toUser = payload.get("TOUSER");
            String toUserRegid = regIdMap.get(toUser);

            String message = createJsonMessage(toUserRegid, getRandomMessageId(),
                    payload, collapseKey, null, false);
            send(message);
        } 

    }

    /**
     * Handles an ACK.
     *
     * <p>
     * By default, it only logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it
     * to properly handle ACKS.
     */
    public void handleAckReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
        String messageId = jsonObject.get("message_id").toString();
        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleAckReceipt() from: " + from
                + ", messageId: " + messageId);
    }

    /**
     * Handles a NACK.
     *
     * <p>
     * By default, it only logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it
     * to properly handle NACKS.
     */
    public void handleNackReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
        String messageId = jsonObject.get("message_id").toString();
        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleNackReceipt() from: " + from
                + ", messageId: " + messageId);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a JSON encoded GCM message.
     *
     * @param to
     *            RegistrationId of the target device (Required).
     * @param messageId
     *            Unique messageId for which CCS will send an "ack/nack"
     *            (Required).
     * @param payload
     *            Message content intended for the application. (Optional).
     * @param collapseKey
     *            GCM collapse_key parameter (Optional).
     * @param timeToLive
     *            GCM time_to_live parameter (Optional).
     * @param delayWhileIdle
     *            GCM delay_while_idle parameter (Optional).
     * @return JSON encoded GCM message.
     */
    public static String createJsonMessage(String to, String messageId,
            Map<String, String> payload, String collapseKey, Long timeToLive,
            Boolean delayWhileIdle) {
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        message.put("to", to);
        if (collapseKey != null) {
            message.put("collapse_key", collapseKey);
        }
        if (timeToLive != null) {
            message.put("time_to_live", timeToLive);
        }
        if (delayWhileIdle != null && delayWhileIdle) {
            message.put("delay_while_idle", true);
        }
        message.put("message_id", messageId);
        message.put("data", payload);
        return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a JSON encoded ACK message for an upstream message received from
     * an application.
     *
     * @param to
     *            RegistrationId of the device who sent the upstream message.
     * @param messageId
     *            messageId of the upstream message to be acknowledged to CCS.
     * @return JSON encoded ack.
     */
    public static String createJsonAck(String to, String messageId) {
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        message.put("message_type", "ack");
        message.put("to", to);
        message.put("message_id", messageId);
        return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
    }

    /**
     * Connects to GCM Cloud Connection Server using the supplied credentials.
     *
     * @param username
     *            GCM_SENDER_ID@gcm.googleapis.com
     * @param password
     *            API Key
     * @throws XMPPException
     */
    public void connect(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {
        config = new ConnectionConfiguration(GCM_SERVER, GCM_PORT);
        config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
        config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
        config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
        config.setSendPresence(false);
        config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

        // NOTE: Set to true to launch a window with information about packets
        // sent and received
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        // -Dsmack.debugEnabled=true
        XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();

        connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
                logger.info("Reconnecting..");
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnection failed.. ", e);
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnecting in %d secs", seconds);
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection closed on error.");
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosed() {
                logger.info("Connection closed.");
            }
        });

        // Handle incoming packets
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Received: " + packet.toXML());
                Message incomingMessage = (Message) packet;
                GcmPacketExtension gcmPacket = (GcmPacketExtension) incomingMessage
                        .getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE);
                String json = gcmPacket.getJson();
                try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Map<String, Object> jsonObject = (Map<String, Object>) JSONValue
                            .parseWithException(json);

                    // present for "ack"/"nack", null otherwise
                    Object messageType = jsonObject.get("message_type");

                    if (messageType == null) {
                        // Normal upstream data message
                        handleIncomingDataMessage(jsonObject);

                        // Send ACK to CCS
                        String messageId = jsonObject.get("message_id")
                                .toString();
                        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();
                        String ack = createJsonAck(from, messageId);
                        send(ack);
                    } else if ("ack".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                        // Process Ack
                        handleAckReceipt(jsonObject);
                    } else if ("nack".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                        // Process Nack
                        handleNackReceipt(jsonObject);
                    } else {
                        logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                                "Unrecognized message type (%s)",
                                messageType.toString());
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing JSON " + json, e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't send echo.", e);
                }
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

        // Log all outgoing packets
        connection.addPacketInterceptor(new PacketInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void interceptPacket(Packet packet) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent: {0}", packet.toXML());
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

        connection.login(username, password);
    }

    public void writeToFile(String name, String regId) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> regIdMap = readFromFile();
        regIdMap.put(name, regId);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                REG_ID_STORE, false)));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : regIdMap.entrySet()) {
            out.println(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue());
        }
        out.println(name + "," + regId);
        out.close();

    }

    public Map<String, String> readFromFile() {
    Map<String, String> regIdMap = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(REG_ID_STORE));
        String regIdLine = "";
        regIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while ((regIdLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] regArr = regIdLine.split(",");
            regIdMap.put(regArr[0], regArr[1]);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
    }
        return regIdMap;
    }

 public static void main(String [] args) {
    final String userName = "835028158552" + "@gcm.googleapis.com";
    final String password = "AIzaSyDFAm7tJT_CXlIpWaTN9LsTIykVbxB-mOA";

    SmackCcsClient ccsClient = new SmackCcsClient();

    try {
      ccsClient.connect(userName, password);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this, i am stuck here as well, please guide if you have resolved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think this code from Google as a client to the Google's XMPP server despite the fact that for you is the server. Those two lines

```
public static final String GCM_SERVER = "gcm.googleapis.com";  
public static final int GCM_PORT = 5235;
```

state the URL and the port of the Google's XMPP server. It is where the code you have posted connected to.